# Quick overview of the essential Dhammas in Buddhism

Tags: discussion

[There is this great website](http://www.insightmeditationcenter.org/books-articles/dhamma-lists/#formjhanas) which gives a quick overview of the *essential dhammas* in Buddhism together with translation of *pali terms* and an overview explanation of *the Tipitaka*. I find this very useful as quick-encyclopedia.

The Dhamma list is also available for download as a PDF-file.

I tried to copy and paste the list into a text box here but its very difficult since it destroys the formatting and it takes a long time to clean it up.

Could we somehow get the list on Buddhism SE so other users can benefit from it too?

Comment: I've just put another idea in this [meta question](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/1615/157) of where we could put useful resources such as your Dhamma list. Might be a good place to keep it?

Answer (score 1):

That's enormously helpful. I was going to ask a question about all the lists to see if someone had collated them - but it's already been excellently done here. I'm not sure about the best way to get a list of resources.

What about a meta question (or a main site question as a wiki) asking for peoples favourite resources (like the classics such as access to insight and the lesser known). When we could edit it down and format it then perhaps put a featured tag on it.

Or there could be another way to do it. I think of ChrisW as the stack exchange engine expert so maybe he has some ideas

Comment: Sounds like some good ideas. Let's see what Chris will say about it. I could do it the old fashion way and copy/paste it into an answer and then format it all so it will look like on the website it links to. Problem is when one copy/paste it it is inserted as a big clump of text. I do think that we should do something since this is really beneficial, especially for new comers who needs to have a quick dhamma-overview when studying the texts.

Comment: That is a really nice, concise "list of lists" for a more Theravada based study. There would be several differences for students of Mahayana such as 6 perfections rather than 10, focus on Bodhisatva rather than 4 stages of enlightenment I think, etc. But the idea of a wiki of helpful links seems like a really good idea. There have been a lot of great links built into particular answers that would be wonderful to have in one place as a resource. Is there a quick way of finding out what wiki's we already have? Maybe I've just missed something obvious but I can't seem to spot our current wiki's.

Comment: @Robin111 http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3ayes%20is%3aquestion

Comment: Help with advanced features of Search: [How do I search?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Comment: Great, thanks @ChrisW! I've been wondering what our wiki selection consisted of. :)

Comment: @Robin. Good you mention the other traditions we should of course also have them in an answer too. I have posted a question about it now. Would you mind checking it and see if it looks OK or if something should be altered?

Comment: @Lanka, I think your question looks good. Great idea. :)